# React array filtering is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, array-filter

I'm working on a simple todos app and I'm stuck at a point. Basically, my array filtering is not working. It's not doing anything in fact and I couldn't find out why. I'm using Material UI in the app and I'm suspecting there is something related to that but couldn't figure out entirely.

I'm trying to delete one todo by clicking the trash icon which triggers "deleteTodo" function. But it's not deleting it from the todos. Actually, as I said it's doing nothing. I'm keeeping my todos in the localStorage.

Here is my delete one todo function:

```
    function deleteTodo(id) {
        setTodos(todos.filter((todo,i,arr) => {
            console.log("id:", id)
            console.log("todo.id:",todo.id)
            console.log("are equal:", todo.id === id)
            console.log(i, arr)
            return (todo.id !== id)
        }))
    }
```

console output:

```
[Log] id: – "37dbcd88d5a"
[Log] todo.id: – "37dbcd88d5a"
[Log] are equal: – true
[Log] 1 – [{text: "two", done: false, id: "7dbcd88d5a3"}, {text: "one", done: false, id: "37dbcd88d5a"}] (2)
```

my component as a whole:

```
import { uid } from 'uid'
import { useState , useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react"
import { Card, CardContent, Modal, List, ListItem, Box, Button, IconButton, TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material"
import styles from "../styles/Todos.module.css"
import { TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import ReportProblemIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ReportProblem';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import EditIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Edit';


export default function Todos () {
    const [ text, setText ] = useState("")
    const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState([])
    const [ showClearTodosModal, setShowClearTodosModal] = useState(false)
    const inputRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        // localStorage.todos && console.log('b1:',JSON.parse(localStorage.todos))
        if (localStorage.todos) {
            // localStorage.todos && console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.todos))
            setTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.todos))
        } else {
            localStorage.todos = []
        }
        // localStorage.todos && console.log('a1:',JSON.parse(localStorage.todos))
    }, [])
    useEffect(() => {
        if (todos && todos.length > 0) {
            localStorage.todos && console.log('b2:',JSON.parse(localStorage.todos))
            localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
            localStorage.todos && console.log('a2:',JSON.parse(localStorage.todos))
        }
    }, [todos])

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const id = uid()
        setTodos([{text, done:false, id:id}, ...todos])
        setText("")
    }

    function markDone(e) {
        setTodos(todos.map(todo => {
            if (e.target.innerText === todo.text) {
                return {...todo, done:!todo.done}
            } else {
                return todo
            }
        }))
    }

    function deleteTodo(id) {
        setTodos(todos.filter((todo,i,arr) => {
            console.log("id:", id)
            console.log("todo.id:",todo.id)
            console.log("are equal:", todo.id === id)
            console.log(i, arr)
            return (todo.id !== id)
        }))
    }
    function deleteAll() {
        setTodos([])
        setShowClearTodosModal(false)
        localStorage.removeItem("todos")
    }

    return (
        <Box>
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
                <TextField 
                    className={styles.entryfield}
                    label="Add a todo"
                    autoFocus
                    value={text}
                    onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
                    ref={inputRef}
                />
            </form>

            <Button 
                 color="primary" 
                 aria-label="upload picture" 
                 component="span"
                    className={styles.clearall} 
                    onClick={() => setShowClearTodosModal(true)}
                startIcon={<ReportProblemIcon />}
            >
                Delete All Todos
            </Button>
            <Modal
              open={showClearTodosModal}
              onClose={() => setShowClearTodosModal(false)}
              aria-labelledby="delete all todos"
              aria-describedby="delete all todos"
              className={styles.deleteallmodal}
            >
              <Box className={styles.modalbox}>
                <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                    Delete all todos?
                </Typography>
                <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                    Are you sure you want to delete all todos? This action is irreversable and you will lose all of your todos.
                </Typography>
                <Button
                    onClick={() => setShowClearTodosModal(false)}
                    variant="contained"
                    sx={{m:1}}
                >
                Nah, don't delete my todos
                </Button>
                <Button 
                    onClick={deleteAll}
                    variant="contained"
                    startIcon={<ReportProblemIcon />}
                    sx={{
                        m:1,
                        color: "maroon",
                    }}
                >
                Yes I&apos;m sure delete all of them
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Modal>

            <List>
            {todos && todos.map(todo =>(
                <ListItem 
                    key={todo.id}
                    onClick={markDone}
                >
                    <Card className={styles.card}
                    >
                            <IconButton 
                                className={styles.icons}
                                onClick={() => {deleteTodo(todo.id)}}
                                aria-label="delete"
                            >
                              <DeleteIcon fontSize="small"/>
                            </IconButton>
                            <IconButton 
                                className={styles.icons}
                                aria-label="edit"
                            >
                              <EditIcon fontSize="small"/>
                            </IconButton>
                            <Typography
                                    variant="body1"
                                    style= {{
                                        color: todo.done ? "#555" : "",
                                        margin: 10,
                                    }}
                            >
                                {todo.text}
                            </Typography>
                    </Card>
                </ListItem>
                )
            )}
            </List>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your full code! It was helpful to understand what was happening.

The culprit line that's causing you the headache is here:

```
<ListItem 
  key={todo.id}
  onClick={markDone}
                >
                    <Card className={styles.card}
                    >
                            <IconButton 
                                className={styles.icons}
                                onClick={() => {deleteTodo(todo.id)}}
                                aria-label="delete"
                            >
```

Specifically, **onClick={markDone}** on ListItem. You put the markDone function on the whole list item. So clicking on the IconButton causes the ListItem event to be triggered too.

I know you have the `e.preventDefault()` but unfortunately the order is reversed here with event bubbling (starts inside out and you need stopPropagation instead of preventDefault): I put some logs in deleteTodo and markDone to indicate the start and end of each function and this is the order. This was the output:

```
Todos.tsx:82 deleteTodo start
Todos.tsx:86 deleteTodo end
Todos.tsx:66 markdone start
Todos.tsx:76 markdone end
```

So what's likely happening is react is either doing the setTodos sequentially or batching them, but either way it looks like the setTodos from markDone is taking precedence, and the setTodo there is just a map of the same values again. Hence why clicking the delete button leads to no changes and the same todo items remaining.

Possible solutions could include

a) Add the event as a parameter to `deleteTodo` and run `e.stopPropagation()` at the top of the function to prevent event bubbling further.

```
function deleteTodo(e, id) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('deleteTodo start');
    setTodos(
      todos.filter((todo, i, arr) => {
        return todo.id !== id;
      })
    );
    console.log('deleteTodo end');
  }
```

and setup your IconButton:

```
<IconButton
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    deleteTodo(e, todo.id);
                  }}
```

This should help stop the event from bubbling further up (I confirmed this to be working locally).

b) You could remove the onClick={markDone} and add a separate button to do the mark done action (removing the onClick is confirmed to make your delete method work)

c) You keep the markDone but do some additional conditional checking on the `e` event target to see if the delete button was hit - if it was, return early in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working codesandbox of your component. Please align your code with my example and be sure that you do not have any other wrong implementations in your code
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shadow-7lz1o0?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { text: "two", done: false, id: "7dbcd88d5a3" },
    { text: "one", done: false, id: "37dbcd88d5a" },
    { text: "one", done: false, id: "643dbcd88d5a" }
  ]);

  function deleteTodo(id) {
    setTodos(
      todos.filter((todo, i, arr) => {
        console.log("id:", id);
        console.log("todo.id:", todo.id);
        console.log("are equal:", todo.id === id);
        console.log(i, arr);
        return todo.id !== id;
      })
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {todos &&
        todos.map((todo) => (
          <div key={todo.id}>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  deleteTodo(todo.id);
                }}
                aria-label="delete"
              >
                {todo.id}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
let testArray = [{text: "two", done: false, id: "7dbcd88d5a3"}, {text: "one", done: false, id: "37dbcd88d5a"},
{text: "one", done: false, id: "643dbcd88d5a"}]

function deleteTodo(id) { 
        console.log(testArray.filter((todo,i,arr) => {
        return (todo.id !== id)}))
}

deleteTodo('7dbcd88d5a3');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see which part of your code is different than mine. Can you point out please and if you can elaborate on why mine is not working it would be great. Thanks.